# C++ not printing emojis as expected

Tags: c++, emoji

I have the following extract of a program

```cpp
int main(){
  cout << "1) ✊\n";
  cout << "2) ✋\n";
  cout << "3) ✌️\n";

}
```

But at the time I run it I get strange texts like the following

```
====================
rock paper scissors!
====================
1) Ô£è
2) Ô£ï
3) Ô£î´©Å
```

This seems not to be related to my terminal but instead to a compilation result because if I run `echo ✊` it shows as expected.

See example below
[image: console output for the program and echo program]

I'm currently using the following compilation commands and compiler version
`g++ *.cpp -o rock_paper_scissors.exe`

> g++.exe (Rev9, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0
> Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Finally, note that it was working before as expected, but at some point, it stopped working, I noticed after I used `system("pause")` which I'm guessing may have changed something on the compilation configurations as this is a Windows-only command, I delete such piece of code and still having the issue.

You can see the rest of the code here: https://github.com/guillene/RockPaperScissors

Comment: The standard `cout` stream only handles 8-bit encodings.  Emojis require more than 8 bits to represent.  You'll need another stream that can accommodate the extra bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your terminal font supports emojis and you don't want to write much code (like switching from cout to wcout), you can use the windows api function below.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
  std::cout << "1) ✊\n";
  std::cout << "2) ✋\n";
  std::cout << "3) ✌️\n";
  return 0;
}
```

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp

Comment: Thank you! SetConsoleOutputCP did the trick for me. I also tried wcout and printf but they didn't work either.

Comment: io operations in c++ are complex.
You can "accept" the answer if it works for you.